# Electric shock when touching my networked installation (behind UPS)

Tags: networking, security, electric-shock

Every time I touch my computer, the TV stand, the switch or when manipulating the shielded network cables if I touch my central heating (just next to the installation) I get an electric shock.

If I hold my hand touching any of these items and the heater I feel current passing... Even holding for a few seconds I keep getting shocked, so static is definitely not involved.

Should I "fix" this? Is this situation dangerous for my computers/game consoles and TVs? As nearly everything is connected using Ethernet in my house I am worried.

What are the steps to fix it?

Comment: There is obviously a ground problem and it is dangerous. Definitely "fix" it.

Comment: @Xavierjazz How should I proceed? What would be at least the first steps to pinpoint the probable cause of the problem?

Comment: @Coyote - Call an electrician, it's clearly not just the computer.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you've got a floating ground.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_ground

Comment: Any idea on how to "fix" or at least attenuate this?

Comment: As @Shinrai notes, call an electrician.  This is a dangerous issue and needs professional attention.

Comment: The floating ground could be the HVAC ducting, moving air can build up enough static electricity to create a continuous current, plain old induction and antenna effect can put a potential on a large enough area of sheet metal to zap you. I'd check the electrical system grounds to make sure they are intact and bond the ducting to electrical ground as well.

Answer (score 1):

One of your electronic devices is not properly grounded. so it's using that metallic material to complete the circuit between itself and ground. I would highly suggest getting that figured out and fixed. It could damage your electronics. if the voltage is high enough, it could damage you. unless you want your last task in life to be completing a circuit, get it fixed.